# Как сделать, чтобы текст не выходил за див?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы текст не выходил за див?

```
.mail {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 13px;
    height: 307px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    width: 92%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

и

```
<div id="mail" class="mail">
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: если это возможно используйте [word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

Comment: он тоже не сильно поможет в данном случае.

Comment: Ответ с "overflow-x:hidden; в класс" мне помог. Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно задать ширину дива в пикселях, тогда все перенестись должно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Если в тексте не будет пробелов то текст всегда будет выходить за рамки! Это факт!
А если с пробелами напишешь то все будет гуд.

добавь

> overflow-x:hidden; в класс

тогда текст который будет выходить за пределы div показываться не будет, а иначе "Текст без пробелов не переносится, это такое правило."

Comment: а можно как-то заблакировать написанное  если, там нет пробелов?

Comment: Обновил, сомтри

Comment: только это не сильно правильно, правильнее всё-таки делать пробелы.

Answer (score 11):

`word-wrap: break-word;` рaботает идеально, даже если 1000 букв подряд.

Comment: Скажите, а возможно добавлять тире на место переноса?

Comment: word-wrap: break-word; не работает у меня (